# Set up a Child/Parent relationship with a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

the issue I'm having is I want to set up a custom Wordpress site to manage a single webcomic.  However, I found all the existing Wordpress online comic management plugins do not do what I need it to do.  And since I've done several wordpress sites with custom post types, I figured it might be easier to roll my own.  However, I'm still having difficulty in setting up the custom post type in a way that I need to make this work.

Currently, I want to set up a custom post type with a parent-child relationship.  Basically, where I have 'Issues' as the parent type, and each issue has child 'pages'.  When you're at the end of one issue, the next page will immediately lead to the first page of the next issue.  And, the permalink structure I'm looking to achieve is something similar to:

site.com/issue-1/page-1/

I've looked at other examples to relate a parent/child relationship with custom post types, but I haven't found anything close to what I'm looking for yet.

I am familiar with the basics of creating and registering custom post types and taxonomies, but not much more than that at the moment.

Comment: Have a look here: [Can a custom post type have a Parent Page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81711/can-a-custom-post-type-have-a-parent-page)

Comment: It's not a parent 'page', it's parent custom post type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your custom post type, add `'hierarchical' => true` to your post types options. That will make it behave like standard pages and let you use a parent/child, one -> many hierarchy.

Comment: This is correct, I also had to put 'page-attributes' in the 'supports' array. From https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#hierarchical

Comment: @alexg Thank you! This worked for me.